# Allow only one number in grep Regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have to accept the strings that only have a single number, it doesn't matter the content of the string, it just needs to be a single number.

I was trying something like this:

```
echo "exaaaamplee1" | grep '[0-9]\{1\}'
```

This string is accepted, but this string also is accepted:

```
echo "exaaaamplee11" | grep '[0-9]\{1\}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use something like `[^0-9]`. This represents any character except a digit 0-9, and you can use [0-9] (or \d) for the one digit that is allowed.

Something like `^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$` should match any string with exactly one digit. (^ being the start and $ the end of the string)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match a string with only one digit character using grep, it's

```sh
echo whatever1 | grep '^[^[:digit:]]*[[:digit:]][^[:digit:]]*$'
```

Start of line followed by any number of non-digits, one digit, and then any number of non-digits until the end of the line.